# Unable to get Aggregator to work

Tags: spring-integration, aggregator, aggregators

I am trying to understand the Aggregator basics. Below is the use case I am trying to implement:

1) Read message (order details) from queue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order xmlns="http://www.example.org/orders">
  <orderItem>
    <isbn>12333454443</isbn>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </orderItem>
  <orderItem>
    <isbn>545656777</isbn>
    <quantity>50</quantity>
  </orderItem>
..
..
</order>
```

One **order** message will contain multiple **orderItem**.  And we can expect hundreds of **order** messages in the queue.

2) End Result ::

a) Each **orderitem** should be written to a file.

b) **4** such files should be written to a unique folder.

To give an example, lets say we got two **order** messages - each containing three **orderitem**.

So we need to create 2 folders :

In "folder 1", there should be 4 files(1 **orderitem** in each file)

In "folder 2", there should be 2 files(1 **orderitem** in each file). Here for simplicity we assume no more **order** messages came and we can write after 5 mins.

Implementation:

---

1. I am able to read the message from the queue (websphere MQ) and unmarshall the message successfully.
2. Used splitter to split the message based on **orderitem** count.
3. Used Aggregator to group the message in size of 4.

I unable to get the aggregator to work as per my understanding.

1. I push one **order** when 4 **orderitem**, the message is getting aggregated correctly.
2. I push one **order** with 5 **orderitem**, the first 4 is getting aggregated but the last one is sent to discard channel. This is expected as the MessageGroup is released so the last message is discarded.
3. I push two **orders** each containing 2 **orderitem**. The last 2 **orderitem** are sent to discard channel.
   The correlation strategy is hardcoded (OrderAggregator.java) but the above case should have worked.

Need pointers on how to implement this use case where I can group them in 4 and write to unique folders.
Please note that the **orderitem** are all independent book orders and have no relation amongst them.

Below is the configuration.

## spring-bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
  <int:channel id="mqInbound"/>
  <int:channel id="item"/>
  <int:channel id="itemList"/>
  <int:channel id="aggregatorDiscardChannel"/>

  <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
                                      channel="mqInbound"
                                      destination="requestQueue" 
                                      message-   converter="orderMessageConverter"/>

  <int:splitter input-channel="mqInbound"  output-channel="item" expression="payload.orderItem"/>

  <int:chain id="aggregateList" input-channel="item" output-channel="itemList"  >
    <int:header-enricher>
      <int:header name="sequenceSize" expression="4" overwrite="true"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:aggregator  correlation-strategy="orderAggregator" correlation-strategy-method="groupOrders"  discard-channel="aggregatorDiscardChannel" />
  </int:chain>

  <int:service-activator input-channel="itemList"                 ref="displayAggregatedList" method="display"/>
  <int:service-activator input-channel="aggregatorDiscardChannel" ref="displayAggregatedList" method="displayDiscarded"/>

  <bean id="orderAggregator"       class="com.samples.Aggregator.OrderAggregator"/>
  <bean id="displayAggregatedList" class="com.samples.Aggregator.DisplayAggregatedList"/>
  ...
  ....
</beans>
```

## OrderAggregator.java

```
public class OrderAggregator {

@Aggregator
public List<OrderItemType> sendList(List<OrderItemType> orderItemTypeList) {

    return orderItemTypeList;
}

@CorrelationStrategy
public String groupOrders( OrderItemType orderItemType) {

    return "items";
}

}
```

## DisplayAggregatedList.java

```
public class DisplayAggregatedList {

public void display(List <OrderItemType> orderItemTypeList) {

    System.out.println("######## Display Aggregated ##############");
    for(OrderItemType oit : orderItemTypeList) {
        System.out.println("### Isbn :" + oit.getIsbn() + ":: Quantity :" + oit.getQuantity());
    }
}
public void displayDiscarded(Message<?> message) {

    System.out.println("######## Display Discarded ##############" + message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called [`expire-groups-upon-completion`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator-config):

> When set to true (default false), completed groups are removed from the message store, allowing subsequent messages with the same correlation to form a new group. The default behavior is to send messages with the same correlation as a completed group to the discard-channel.

If you need to release uncompleted groups anyway (2 orders left, for example), consider to use `group-timeout`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#agg-and-group-to

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan for your response. The aggregator seems to be working inconsistently for my code.  Depending on the number of messages I push,  sometimes it works.

However the below sequence of messages is **not working**.
**1)** Post order message with 3 orderitem. (isbn # : 001, 002, 003) 
**2)** Post order message with 1 orderitem. (isbn # : 004 ) 

The messages should be released after the second message. However the second message ( Isbn : 004) is seen in the **discard channel**.

Comment: Below scenerio works:
**1)** Post order message with 5 orderitem. (isbn # : 011, 012, 013, 014, 015)
**2)** Post order message with 5 orderitem. (isbn # : 016, 017, 018, 019, 020)
**3)** Post order message with 2 orderitem. (isbn # : 021, 022)
**Three message groups are released**.  group#1 (011,012,013,014), group#2 (015,016,017,018), group#3(019,020,021,022).
However for some reason the earlier sequence ( 3 orderitem + 1 orderitem) as shared in my last comment does not work

Comment: Please, use `expire-groups-upon-completion="true" and consider to use `MessageCountReleaseStrategy` for `release-strategy`

Answer (score 0):

Please, use expire-groups-upon-completion="true" and consider to use MessageCountReleaseStrategy` for release-strategy – Artem Bilan